# Haskell program coverage

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-program-coverage

I'm trying to use the `ghc -fhpc` command in order to create a `.tix` file, but after I enter the command `ghc -fhpc filename`, nothing appears.

What should I do?

Comment: try addin `--make -fforce-recomp` to the compiler flags

Comment: i tried, but still nothing appear. 
i compiled the program like this "ghc filename.hs" and it compiled without any problem. After i did " ghc -fhpc --make -fforce-recomp filename". Did i something wrong?

Comment: If Cabal is used to generate the coverage report, there is a flag:

```--test-keep-tix-files          keep .tix files for HPC between test runs```

Answer (score 3):

You must execute the program. HPC shows the coverage of a particular run, it isn't a static analysis that occurs at compile time.

EDIT

For example.  Does this not work for you?

```
% cat x.hs
main = getChar >>= print
% ghc -fforce-recomp -fhpc x.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( x.hs, x.o )
Linking x ...
% ./x
x
'x'
% ls x.tix
x.tix
```

If the above doesn't work then you have a tooling issue.

EDIT 2:

If your program isn't terminating normally then the `.tix` file might not be getting written.  You need a normal termination and not some sort of segfaulted or otherwise-aborted run.

Comment: if i execute it, i will get the result of using TestList that i put in the .hs file. Something like "Cases: 2 Tried: 2 ...".

Comment: @VitorDias ...and presumably *also* a tix file, no?

Comment: No, thats the problem...if i get it i would be able to do the next command i want "hpc report filename.tix"

Comment: @VitorDias See my edit.  If you can't reproduce my results there then I suspect you should try reinstalling GHC.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I dont know exactly why, but i did "ghc -fforce-recomp -fhpc x.hs" and i get it. 
Thank you very much!